# Spoon vs fork vs airdrop

Tags: forks, airdrop

Can someone explain the exact differences between the three?

I'm most familiar with the fork, where the rules of generating blocks change creating a fork where miners can choose to follow the old rules or the new rules.

An airdrop is simply taking the balances of an existing blockchain to distribute a token on a new independent blockchain.

What is the spoon? I've read some introductions to it and it sounds like a sort of hybrid but I don't quite get it. An ELI5 approach would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A "hard spoon" is a less common concept with more information being found in [this article](https://themerkle.com/what-is-a-hard-spoon/), but I believe this snippet may help you understand better:

> A hard spoon essentially is a new blockchain which takes the account state of an existing chain into account. People familiar with the concept of a hard fork will recall that some projects take a “snapshot” of an existing blockchain and issue the newly created tokens accordingly. While this does not necessarily warrant a novel approach, the hard spoon is not focused on competition.

Comment: That sounds identical to a Genesis block airdrop to me. What exactly is the difference?